# Render becomes blurry

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

So I downloaded a blend from blendswap and here's the issue. When I load it, it's fine. When I render it, it's initially fine. Then there's something like another layer or something added on top of the render and it becomes very blurry. I am working in 2.8 with Eevee but the same thing is happening in cycles. The original version before the "extra layer" or whatever it is as well as the blurry version can both be found below.

EDIT: I've added a picture of the compositing nodes as well.

[image: Non-Blurry]

[image: Blurry]

[image: Compositing Nodes]

Answer (score 1):

Try going to the node tree... See if there's another layer being composited on top.  Also, I'd check out the depth of field under the camera settings, and make sure that it isn't messing stuff up...

Comment: Definitely not the camera, as I've tried both and there's no abnormal settings as far as I can see. Gonna try the node tree. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help.  Whenever you get these problems, and it looks good, initially, then something weird happens, its usually the node tree.

Comment: @ElliotWren Don't post thanks in the comments, instead upvote the answer. If it solved our problem consider marking it as accepted